# Morphology interefering with Wordforms in Sphinx

Tags: sphinx, stemming

With stem_en on 'Children' = 'Childrens' and vice-versa w/o any wordforms.

If I map Children to Term2 in wordformsthan ONLY Children maps to Term2, not Childrens. Assuming I have told Sphinx to remove Children from the morphology by adding it to wordform.

Is there no way to tell Sphinx I want the Children/Childrens stem_all to be used and I want to map Children to a non-morphology related word (Term2)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the ~ operation

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-wordforms

> Starting with version 2.1.1-beta, ...  Finally, if a line starts with a tilde ("~") the wordform will be applied after morphology, instead of before.

So that wordforms dont implement stemming exceptions, but work on stemmed versions.